# What does it mean for a force to 'produce' virtual displacement?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, work, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

Book: **Variational Principles of Mechanics** by **Lanczos**, 1st edition, 1949.

Statement (page 80):

> **"Two systems of forces which produce the same virtual displacements are dynamically equivalent."**

I don't understand the part about forces *producing* virtual displacements. I think of virtual displacements as infinitesimal variations from a path between two points on the configuration space. But these variations are arbitrary. How are the forces, which are certainly *not* arbitrary, *producing* these virtual displacements?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277410/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129786/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203600/

Answer (score 0):

In the 4th edition from 1970 the quoted sentence on p. 80 was changed to:

> *Two systems of forces which produce the same virtual **work** are dynamically equivalent.*

This means in particular that we can ignore forces associated with zero virtual work, cf. the [principle of virtual work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work) and [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle).