# How Lagrangian equations of motions can be obtained from Newton's laws?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Let's consider a system of $N$ point particles. Let's also assume that acceleration of each particle is a function of positions of all the particles.

I assume that for such a system we can prove that the motion of the system is described by Lagrangian equations of motion.

How exactly can it be done?

**ADDED**

I do not ask why Lagrangian is defined as $L = T - V$. What I am interested is how to derive Lagrangian equations of motion from Newtonian equations of motion.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/344720/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292710/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Roman. Welcome to Phys.SE. Your added question directly follows from q 78138.