# Physical significance of virtual displacement

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, definition, constrained-dynamics

I have found many posts on this topic but I am not really able to understand what [virtual displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement) means in classical mechanics. Is there any simple way of explanation without going into rigorous mathematics?

Comment: More on [virtual displacement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+virtual+displacement*). Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129786/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I'm not conversant on virtual displacement, but for me the physical significance is the related subject of virtual work, which is an alternative, energy based way of determining static equilibrium requirements.

Comment: @Bob D I am also searching for such an answer to this question but no one is giving any answer.