# Derivation of virtual displacement transformation rule

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, calculus, variational-calculus

In my studies to Lagrangian Mechanics I've come across a particular transformation rule:
([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work), [Nolting](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-41980-5))
$$
\delta \mathbf{r}_i = \sum_j \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_i}{\partial q_j} \delta q_j
$$

Which looks a lot like a rule for calculating the differential of a function (from differential geometry):
$$
\mathrm{d}f = \sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial q_j} \mathrm{d}q_j
$$

But as far as I can understand, the first rule is something different.
I wanted to derive that, but I'm not sure, whether I made the right conclusions.

In [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129786/) an intuition is given for what a *virtual displacement* is, some extension of the configuration manifold with another parameter $s$ which is independent from the time parameter $t$ (because we define it that way).

Using this definition, I define for each and every point in time $t$ a curve in the configuration space given by
$$
\mathbf{r}^\ast_i = \mathbf{r}^\ast_i(q_1(s),q_2(s),\ldots,q_j(s),t) = \mathbf{r}^\ast_i(s) \\
\mathbf{r}^\ast_i(s = 0 ) = \mathbf{r}_i(q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_j,t)
$$
with $\mathbf{r}_i$ being the current coordinates along the motion induced by $t$ (saying, $s$ always starts from something that actually happens)

This allows us to define the *virtual displacement* (again, from the answer in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129786/what-exactly-is-a-virtual-displacement-in-classical-mechanics))
$$
\mathbf{r}_i^\ast(s) - \mathbf{r}_i
$$

So far, so normal. Now, the curve defined by $s$ spans a submanifold, and we are interested in its Tangential-Space, meaning we take it's **differential** restricted to $s$:
$$
\mathrm{d}_s(\mathbf{r}_i^\ast(s) - \mathbf{r}_i) = \mathrm{d}_s\mathbf{r}_i^\ast(s) - \mathrm{d}_s\mathbf{r}_i = \mathrm{d}_s\mathbf{r}_i^\ast(s)\\
= \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}_i^\ast(s)}{\partial s} \mathrm{d}s = 
\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}_i^\ast(q_1(s),q_2(s),\ldots,q_j(s),t)}{\partial s} \mathrm{d}s
= \sum_j \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}_i^\ast}{\partial q_j} \frac{\partial q_j}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}s
$$
Implying
$$
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_i^\ast(s) = \sum_j \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}_i^\ast}{\partial q_j} \frac{\partial q_j}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}s
$$
If I now guess correctly, speaking of a **differential restricted to a submanifold** is a mouthful to say and will be confusing in notation, we intruduce the $\delta$ as a shorthand for this special restricted differential
$$
\delta \mathbf{r}_i^\ast(s) = \sum_j \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}_i^\ast}{\partial q_j} \frac{\partial q_j}{\partial s}\delta s =\sum_j \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}_i^\ast}{\partial q_j} \delta q_j \qquad \blacksquare
$$

concluding the derivation.

The Question(s):

1. Is this derivation correct and did it use the correct terminology?
2. Why is there a star ($\mathbf{r}_i^\ast$) in my derivation, but in the original transformation law, there isn't ($\mathbf{r}_i$)? How do we get rid of it?
3. My *virtual generalized coordinates* $\delta q_j$ are tangential components of my curve parameter differential $\mathbf{d}s$, yet in the textbook they are still treated as independent coordinates. Why is that possible?