# Taylor Series and Infinitesimals

Tags: mathematics, calculus

I'm trying to gain a more intuitive understand of the concept of an [infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal). When physicists speak of an infinitesimal quantity, if that basically the same as the first order term in a Taylor series expansion of a function they're analyzing?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70376/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92925/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rigorous underpinnings of infinitesimals in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70376/)

Comment: You might find this informative as background http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/11/03/more-than-infinitesimal-what-is-dx/

Comment: Thank you so much and please accept my apologies for asking a duplicate question. I think I have a much more intuitive appreciation for the concept now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one good way to get an intuitive feel for an infinitesimal is by means of the following challenge: "You give me any small number, as small as you wish, and I'll give you a number even smaller, and yet, an infinitesimal is smaller even than my number."

If we both start this endless game, we might quickly get bored, but hopefully, we would come away with a sense of where we'd go if we went on forever playing.

A similar challenge could be used to get a sense of the infinitely large, or a sense of what it means to approach an asymptotic limit.