# What is infinitesimal displacement?

Tags: differentiation, mathematics, calculus, displacement

This section is from the [Openstax University Physics: Volume 1 online textbook](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/7-1-work).

> In physics, work is done on an object when energy is transferred to
>   the object. In other words, work is done when a force acts on
>   something that undergoes a displacement from one position to another.
>   Forces can vary as a function of position, and displacements can be
>   along various paths between two points. We first define the increment
>   of work $\text dW$ done by a force $\mathbf F$ acting through an infinitesimal
>   displacement $\text d\mathbf r$  as the dot product of these two vectors:

Is it simply just a very small displacement?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92925/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70376/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, infinitesimal just means extremely close to zero.

Comment: Is $10^{-9}$ meters close enough to zero displacement to be an infinitesimal displacement? No. And neither is any other finite displacement. You are ignoring more than 300 years of calculus.

Comment: Hi G. I thought a layman's answer was needed. I picked the word extremely to suggest the limiting value of smallness.