# Product rule of variations

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, differentiation, variational-calculus

I am deriving the Einstein equation using the Einstein-Hilbert action: [image]

It is obvious that the variation in the Riemann Tensor is calculated from a variational product rule. What is not obvious to me is why variations obey this rule, and I'll like an explanation.

Comment: Elementary answer: Variations are derivatives of 1-parameter families of functions, thus they follow the product rule.

Functional answer: Variations are exterior derivatives on the covariant phase space, and as such they follow the (anti-)product rule.

Differential geometric answer: Variations are Lie derivatives on a jet bundle, and as such they follow the product rule.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to go about this is to think of variation in terms of the background field method. Here, you write the metric as some background plus perturbation:

\begin{equation}
g_{\mu \nu} = \bar{g}_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}

and then you expand every quantity that depends on $g_{\mu \nu}$ as a power series in $h$:

$$
\Gamma = \bar{\Gamma} + \Gamma^{(1)} + \Gamma^{(2)} \cdots \\
R = \bar{R} + R^{(1)} + R^{(2)} \cdots
$$

where the superscript $^{(n)}$ labels the $\mathcal{O} (h^n)$ perturbation. You can then easily see that

$$
\Gamma \Gamma = (\bar{\Gamma} + \Gamma^{(1)} + \Gamma^{(2)} \cdots)(\bar{\Gamma} + \Gamma^{(1)} + \Gamma^{(2)} \cdots)
$$

Extracting the $\mathcal{O}(h)$ variation, like in your problem, we automatically get both the contributions:

$$
(\Gamma \Gamma)^{(1)} = \bar{\Gamma} \Gamma^{(1)} +  \Gamma^{(1)} \bar{\Gamma}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It's a fundamental property of infinitesimal variations $\delta$ that they are [linear derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)), i.e. they obey [Leibniz product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule). Short of a [rigorous](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92925/2451) definition of [infinitesimals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70376/2451), the proof is basically to consider variations as 1-parameter families of functions, and then differentiate wrt. the parameter, cf. above comment by Bence Racsko.