Why take the derivative of variables such as area, mass, and radius?
I'm taking a module on stars and the solar system; I've attached notes from our first lecture- hydrostatic equilibrium. I'm confused about the notation $\mathrm{d}$ for $\mathrm{d}A, \, \mathrm{d}r$, and $\mathrm{d}m$. I understand that $\mathrm{d}$ is the derivative operator, signifying an infinitesimal change in the variable it's next to. I'm unsure, however, how to visually think of this "change". Why is mass a function, and why is it changing? With regard to what is it changing? Also, I understand that in this example, "$\mathrm{d}r$" is simply the thickness of the planet/ star's shell. How does that relate to "a change in radius $r$", which I assume is measured from the center of the planet all the way until the shell starts?
Thank you so much for any help!!


See if the discussion here helps a bit. Also, you probably should transcribe the specific equation/s in this image that confuse you via MathJax so that it is easier to read.

When going from radius r to the surface you must travel a distance dr, according to your picture, so that is the change in radius. dm is the mass of a small volume element inside the planet or star or whatever. You can assume it is varying due to the change in pressure or the composition, but here you shouldn't think of it as a varying function, but as I said, the mass of a small volume element

These are differentials not derivatives. You can think of them as "infinitesimal elements of" area, radius, or whatever rather than "changes in" those variables.

About the use of the differentials, you may find useful my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/521643/how-do-physicists-know-when-it-is-appropriate-to-use-mathrm-dx-as-if-it-is-a/521656#521656

Physicists tend to be informal about the $d$ notation, using it initially to represent a relatively small change in a variable, and then eventually dividing one small change by another to produce, out of a hat, a derivative. Mathematicians reach the same end point with a more formal notation in which a small change in a variable is represented by a $\delta$, and the $d$ notation is reserved for the true derivative when we divide one $\delta$ quantity by another $\delta$ quantity and then take the limit as $\delta$ goes to zero (physicists take the limit step as read).
Using the $\delta$ notation, we would say $\delta m$ is the mass of the small cylinder in the diagram, with cross sectional area $\delta A$ and length $\delta r$ (because it lies in the shell between radius $r$ and radius $r+\delta r$). If we call the volume of this small cylinder $\delta V$ then we have
$\delta V = \delta r \cdot \delta A$
But the density of material in the shell between radius $r$ and radius $r+\delta r$ is $\rho(r)$. Here we use the fact that $\delta r$ is small compared with $r$ to make the simplifying assumption that density is approximately constant across the shell. So
$\delta m = \rho(r) \cdot \delta V = \rho(r) \cdot \delta r \cdot \delta A$
It is somewhat confusing that $r$ is used both to represent the generic radius of the planet and also the specific radius of the shell.

Thank you so much! The notation of “d” is much more clear now. However, I’m still confused by how I’d use it in a problem. Is dr, dA, and dm treated as a whole variable whose value will be given, or would I need to calculate it from r, A, and m?

Oh wait! Is the really small change represented by dA, for instance, in reference to how small it is compared to the cross-sectional area of the whole planet?

@canihavealmondmilk Yes, exactly. $dr$, $dm$ and $dA$ are small compared to the radius of the shell, the mass of the shell and the surface area of the shell. We do not need to be specific about how small they are because in the end we will divide one small quantity by another and let both tend towards zero (or "become as small as we like") to produce a derivative.
