# How to relate entropy with change in temperature for a reversible process?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

I am trying to derive the change in entropy for a reversible process.

Let's say there is a body of mass $m$ with some specific heat that is heated reversibly from from a temperature $T_i$ to $T_f$.

Now, we know that the change in energy is $dE = TdS$. We also know that $\frac{dE}{dT} = MC$. Now, if I take $\frac{dE}{dT}$, I get $ dS+T\frac{dS}{dT}$.

Usually, however, I see that the final conclusion is $\frac{dE}{dT} = T\frac{dS}{dT}$. Where did the final $dS$ disappear?

Comment: It's infinitesimal. You can't mix infinitesimal and finite quantities.

Comment: @Chemomechanics what does this mean?

Comment: I mean that $dS$ is [so much smaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_\(mathematics\)) than $T\frac{dS}{dT}$ that their sum is indistinguishable from the latter alone.

Comment: @Chemomechanics How do you know this though?

Comment: All infinitesimals are smaller than any finite number. See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563629/struggling-understanding-definitions-with-infinitesimal-quantities) and the links within ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579287/what-does-dx-mean-without-dy)).

Comment: We know that the change in entropy for a closed system is equal to the integral of dQ/T for a reversible path.  Please articulate the reversible path that you are using to determine the entropy change for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, we know that the change in energy is $dE = TdS$. We also know
> that $\frac{dE}{dT} = MC$. Now, if I take $\frac{dE}{dT}$, I get $
> > dS+T\frac{dS}{dT}$.

I don't see how you got $dS+T\frac{dS}{dT}$.

If

$$dE=TdS$$ and

$$\frac{dE}{dT} = MC$$

it follows that

$$TdS=MCdT$$

or

$$dS=\frac{MCdT}{T}$$

Which is the same as the entropy definition (where $\delta Q_{rev}=dE$) of

$$dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}T=\frac{MCdT}{T}$$

Then, after integrating, the change in entropy between the initial and final temperatures are

$$\Delta S=\int _{Ti}^{Tf}\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}=\int_{Ti}^{Tf}\frac{mMC}{T}dT=MC\ln\frac{T_f}{T_i}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do we decide when to go from a partial derivative to a finite derivative?

Comment: Heat and work are inexact differentials. That's because their integrals are path dependent. Internal energy and entropy are exact differentials. That's because their integrals are path independent.

Comment: I do not think you meant to write $\partial Q_{rev}$

Comment: @hyportnex I meant to write inexact differential. Don't know the Mathjax symbol for it.  Maybe it should be delta $\delta$

Comment: I know what you meant but it seems that *reesespieces* does not. Anyhow I use $\delta $ for the same but you can also try "\not d" to get $\not d$.

Comment: @hyportnex I have seen it written as $\rlap{\textrm{d}}{\bar{\phantom{w}}}$
 and $\delta$. I guess you can add to that $\not d$

Comment: @reesespieces I have edited my answer to replace the partial derivative symbol with a delta symbol to designate it as an inexact differential. Alternative symbols given are $\rlap{\textrm{d}}{\bar{\phantom{w}}}$ and  $\not d$

Comment: The important thing to remember is it makes no sense to talk about a "change" in heat or work, as is the case for a property like internal energy and entropy, but rather an amount of heat or work (amount of energy transfer).

Comment: how do you write this "other d"?

Comment: @hyportnex If you mean the d with the bar across the top, its \rlap{\textrm{d}}{\bar{\phantom{w}}}

Comment: wow, too complicated, ain't worth it, ....

Comment: @hyportnex I agree. $\delta$ appears to be a accepted representation of the  inexact differential of heat in the entropy definition.