# What is the difference between zero and an infinitesimal number?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differentiation, integration, mathematics, calculus

In a standard Atwood machine physics problem, the string going over the pulley is considered massless. So does that imply mass = 0 or mass = dm? General question: what is the difference between 0 and an infinitesimal number?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to treat differentials and infinitesimals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92925/2451) , [Rigorous underpinnings of infinitesimals in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70376/2451) and links therein.

Comment: You will understand the difference between zero and infinitesimal by learning rigorous mathematical analysis. In short, zero $0$ is specific a real number, while infinitesimal is the process of taking limit approaching zero, which is not a number.

Comment: If you say the string has a mass dm and solve the problem, the result will depend on dm. But as you take the limit dm -> 0 in that solution, the result should match the mass = 0 solution. (That no doubt assumes certain mathematical properties of the solution with dm which I'm not qualified to comment on).

Answer (score 0):

A big difference is the fact that you can divide a number by an infinitesimal number. You can't divide a number by zero. So certain terms are sometimes excluded in certain equations because of this fact.