# What exactly is an infinitesimal symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, definition, vector-fields, lie-algebra, calculus

I see this term used a lot, especially in the context of Lie algebras. I have seen it used (though not defined) in both math and physics books, and I could not find a good definition anywhere on the web. One source mentioned that refers to any element of the Lie algebra to a Lie group.

Is there a rigorous definition of an infinitesimal symmetry (and if so, what is it?) or is it used informally akin to $dx$ being an infinitesimal displacement?

Comment: Rigorous? Is your high-school expression $f(x+\epsilon)=f(x) + \epsilon f'(x) + O(\epsilon^2)$ rigorous enough for you?

Comment: @Cosmas: That expression should be rigorous enough for anybody (together with explanations, definitions etc., with context!), right? I don't get your point.

Comment: @kricheli  Where do you reckon is the trouble, then?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I agree that your expression gives a small change in $f$, but how does that relate to symmetries? Putting aside rigor for now, does it mean that we can think of infinitesimal symmetries as an arbitrary small change in the symmetry parameter? For example, if our symmetry is rotation about an angle $\theta$ then we are moving an angle $d\theta$?

Comment: Of course, as most of you sources stress! You seem uncomfortable with differentials, so I bypassed them with ε….

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In a basic setting a [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)) $$\Delta x^i~:=~ x^{\prime i}- x^i~=~ \epsilon X^i +o(\epsilon)\tag{1} $$
   is generated by a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) $$X~=~X^i\partial_i.\tag{2}$$ In eq. (1) we have used the [little-$o$ notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html).
2. In the physics literature, this situation is often transcribed as
   an  *infinitesimal transformation* (IT) or an *infinitesimal vector field* (IVF),
   $$\delta x^i~:=~ x^{\prime i}- x^i~=~ \epsilon X^i,\tag{3} $$
   where $\epsilon$ is an [infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) parameter. Now it turns out that the notion of infinitesimals in [non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) is not easy to make rigorous, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92925/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70376/2451) Phys.SE posts,
   so when pressed what eq. (3) means, a physicist will typically retreat to eq. (1).
3. That the infinitesimal transformation (3) is an *infinitesimal symmetry* (IS) for
   a quantity $Q(x)$ merely means that
   $$\Delta Q~:=~Q(x+\Delta x)-Q(x)~=~o(\epsilon), \tag{4}$$
   where $\Delta x$ is given in eq. (1).
   Equivalently, the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) of the vector field (2) vanishes
   $${\cal L}_X Q~=~0.\tag{5}$$
4. A [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) $\mathfrak{g}$ for a [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) $G$ can be viewed as the set of left-invariant vector fields on $G$ equipped with the [Lie bracket of vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields). Therefore a Lie algebra element is a vector field $X$, which in turn is associated with an infinitesimal transformation (3).

Comment: Thank you, the first part of your answer clarified it for me. For the second part, why does the Lie derivative vanish?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!